# Method doesn't override method from its superclass AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android, appcompatactivity

I am new to Android. I am facing a issue of getting a error called

> "Method doesn't override method from its superclass".

Code is as follows.

```
package com.example.sampleapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Bundle savedInstanceState;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: please provide the full compiler error message.

Comment: did u add compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0' dependencies in your gradle file

Comment: see this https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2015/04/24/example-usage-of-appcompatactivity-in-android/

Comment: It is already added. compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0' #rafsanahmad007

Comment: Not sure why you're storing a reference to the `Activity`'s `Bundle,` but try making it last in `onCreate()` (So the `super` call is first, followed by `setContentView()` and finally `savedInstanceState`).